#  Django: Model Validation Error ManytoManyField

Tags: django, django-models, model-validation

I get this error while running syncdb

Can't seem to figure out the issue. Please help.

```
    Error: One or more models did not validate:
store.business: Reverse query name for field 'logo' clashes with field 'ImageBank.business'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'logo'.
```

Here are my models:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    business_type = models.ManyToManyField(BusinessType)
    business_service_type = models.ManyToManyField(ServiceType)
    establishment_type = models.ForeignKey(EstablishmentType)
    logo = models.ForeignKey(ImageBank, related_name = '%(class)s_logocreated',)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    website = models.URLField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ImageBank(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey('Business', related_name='%(class)s_business')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/bank")

    def url(self):
        return self.image.url

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.business) + " : " + unicode(self.image)
```

Store Model:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business,null=True, related_name='business_creator_set')
    condition = models.CharField(verbose_name='What do customers have to do?',max_length = 50)
    reward = models.CharField(verbose_name='What do customers win?',max_length = 50)
    display = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.condition + ", " + self.reward
```

Comment: Can you add your Store model as well?

Comment: And this still isn't working? Adding the related_name's should've worked

Comment: would it help if i added blank=True null=True?

Comment: You could, but I don't think it'll solve your problem.

Comment: When I ran into this problem, I had two FK fields referencing the same model. All I did was add a related_name to one of them and everything was ok again.

Comment: Did not think so either... Did it anyway and yet nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
...
class ImageBank(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey('Business', related_name='%(class)s_business')
....
```

Also, if that doesn't work, try changing the related_name on the Business.logo field to something not logo_id. logo_id is what the database uses for the field and it may be having a conflict.

Comment: Hmm... what did you change the logo's related_name to? Try something like related_name='%(class)s_logo'

Comment: changed it to that. still nada. crazy i know.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you currently have now?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. It's still giving the EXACT same error as it was in the beginning? If that's the case, then the only thing I can think of is to rename all related_name fields for all FK and M2M fields.